# Iteratively insert a character into different indeces of a string

Tags: python

I am trying to make a Python program that iteratively inserts 1 dot from the beginning to the end, and then 2 dots from the beginning to the end, etc. For example, given a string `abcd`, I want to generate `['abcd', 'a.bcd', 'a.b.cd', 'a.b.c.d', 'a.bc.d', 'ab.cd', 'ab.c.d', 'abc.d']`. Therefore, for a string of length `n`, I want to add up to `n-1` dots in the string.

My code is entirely working for the purpose of adding up to 3 dots, but say I have a string with length 101 and want to add 100 dots, that would mean that I would have to type up 100 for-loops. That's doable, but I was thinking that there is probably a better way to do this, so I wanted to know your thoughts!

```
my_list = []
my_string = "abcd"
my_list.append(my_string) # 0 dots

length = len(my_string)
for i in range(1, length, 1): # insert 1 dot from beginning to end
    new_string = my_string[0:i] + "." + my_string[i:]
    my_list.append(new_string)
    
    for j in range(i+1, length, 1): # insert 2 dots from beginning to end
        new_string = my_string[0:i] + "." + my_string[i:j] + "." + my_string[j:]
        my_list.append(new_string)
        
        for k in range(j+1, length, 1): # insert 3 dots from beginning to end
            new_string = my_string[0:i] + "." + my_string[i:j] + "." + my_string[j:k] + "." + my_string[k:]
            my_list.append(new_string)
    
print(my_list)
```

Comment: You should use recursion to handle an arbitrary number.

Comment: Consider what you might do given `itertools.product(["", "."], repeat=len(my_string) - 1)`.

Comment: You'll also want the `roundrobin` recipe from the `itertools` documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope I do not solve your full school assignment now :) For each position in between two characters you either have a dot or not, we can express this as either 0 or 1. for "abc", this can be:

- `abc = 00`
- `ab.c = 01`
- `a.bc = 10`
- `a.b.c = 11`

This is basically binary counting. We need to list all integer values up to 2^(n)-1, where n is the length of the string - 1. From those you can generate all these strings. Some good old bitwise logic helps.

```
def list_dots(x):
  n = 1 << max(0, len(x) - 1)
  for i in range(n):
    o = ''
    for c in x:
      o += c
      if i & 1:
        o += '.'
      i >>= 1
    yield o
```

Example output

```
>>> list(list_dots('a'))
['a']
>>> list(list_dots('ab'))
['ab', 'a.b']
>>> list(list_dots('abc'))
['abc', 'a.bc', 'ab.c', 'a.b.c']
>>> list(list_dots('abcd'))
['abcd', 'a.bcd', 'ab.cd', 'a.b.cd', 'abc.d', 'a.bc.d', 'ab.c.d', 'a.b.c.d']
```

The output will become rather big if you send in a big string, as it grows O(2^x) where x is the length of the string.

Comment: This isn't really for a homework. I know it seems like it's homework-y because it doesn't seem to have a real-world application, but I actually have a use-case for it. Gmail sends johnsmith@gmail.com any email that's been sent to j.ohnsmith@gmail.com, j.o.hnsmith@gmail.com, etc. I just wanted a list of those equivalent emails. I found your explanation of dots using bits very helpful, but I personally cannot easily follow your code, so I am gonna try and develop my own code using that bit analogy. Thank you!

Comment: ok, glad it was helpful :) E-mails can be pretty long, so you might end up with a long such list. To interpret the code the tutorial about python's bitwise operators can be helpful: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/bitwise_operators_example.htm

Answer (score 1):

```
my_s = "abcdefg"


def enter_dots(s, num_dots):
    if num_dots == 0:
        return [s]

    results = [s]
    lst = list(s)
    for i in range(1, len(lst)):   
        possibility = list(lst)         
        possibility.insert(i, ".")

        # if two dots in same place, disregard possibility
        if possibility[i + 1] == "." or possibility[i - 1] == ".":
            continue

        str_possibility = "".join(possibility)
        results.append(str_possibility)
        results.extend(enter_dots(str_possibility, num_dots - 1))

    return results


print(sorted(list(set(enter_dots(my_s, 3)))))
```

---

Recursion over the number of dots.

If no dots required, return a list containing only the input string.

Otherwise, iterate that string and add dots to it at every possible location.

Send that string back to `enter_dots` with one less dot required.

Finally, kill duplicates (`set`) and `sort` for readability.

---

Output:

> ['a.b.c.defg', 'a.b.cd.efg', 'a.b.cde.fg', 'a.b.cdef.g', 'a.b.cdefg',
> 'a.bc.d.efg', 'a.bc.de.fg', 'a.bc.def.g', 'a.bc.defg', 'a.bcd.e.fg',
> 'a.bcd.ef.g', 'a.bcd.efg', 'a.bcde.f.g', 'a.bcde.fg', 'a.bcdef.g',
> 'a.bcdefg', 'ab.c.d.efg', 'ab.c.de.fg', 'ab.c.def.g', 'ab.c.defg',
> 'ab.cd.e.fg', 'ab.cd.ef.g', 'ab.cd.efg', 'ab.cde.f.g', 'ab.cde.fg',
> 'ab.cdef.g', 'ab.cdefg', 'abc.d.e.fg', 'abc.d.ef.g', 'abc.d.efg',
> 'abc.de.f.g', 'abc.de.fg', 'abc.def.g', 'abc.defg', 'abcd.e.f.g',
> 'abcd.e.fg', 'abcd.ef.g', 'abcd.efg', 'abcde.f.g', 'abcde.fg',
> 'abcdef.g', 'abcdefg']

---

If you want to get rid of duplicates originally, it can be done in several ways, for instance using a `dict`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `product` `chain` and `zip_longest` from [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)

```
>>> from itertools import product, chain, zip_longest
>>> s = 'abcd'
>>> for p in product(['','.'],repeat=len(s)-1):
    print(''.join(chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(s, p,fillvalue=''))))

    
abcd
abc.d
ab.cd
ab.c.d
a.bcd
a.bc.d
a.b.cd
a.b.c.d
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = []
str = 'abcdefg'
strlst = list(str)

lst.append(str)

# Inserts a dot in between the characters
for i in range(1, (len(strlst)*2)-1, 2):
    strlst.insert(i, '.')
    lst.append(''.join(strlst))
print(lst)

# removes the dots from those characters
for i in range(1, (len(str))-1):
    del strlst[i]
    lst.append(''.join(strlst))


print(lst)
```

Output:

> ['abcdefg', 'a.bcdefg', 'a.b.cdefg', 'a.b.c.defg', 'a.b.c.d.efg', 'a.b.c.d.e.fg', 'a.b.c.d.e.f.g']

> ['abcdefg', 'a.bcdefg', 'a.b.cdefg', 'a.b.c.defg', 'a.b.c.d.efg', 'a.b.c.d.e.fg', 'a.b.c.d.e.f.g', 'ab.c.d.e.f.g', 'abc.d.e.f.g', 'abcd.e.f.g', 'abcde.f.g', 'abcdef.g']

Not sure what your looking for but hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Using itertools:

```
from itertools import permutations
string = 'abcd'
{string[0]+''.join(i)+string[-1] 
    for dots in range(1, len(string)) 
    for i in permutations(string[1:-1]+'.'*dots) 
        if ''.join(i).replace('.','') == string[1:-1] and  '.'*2 not in ''.join(i)}
```

Outputs in:

```
{'a.b.c.d', 'a.b.cd', 'a.bc.d', 'a.bcd', 'ab.c.d', 'ab.cd', 'abc.d'}
```